# Why is my UI thread ID usually 9 or 10?

Tags: c#, .net

A few months ago I added a print statement to the constructor of my main `Form` that is created in `Program.cs` along the lines of

```
Console.Out.WriteLine("UI Thread ID: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
```

This usually results in printing `UI Thread ID: 9` about 80% of the time, the other 19% is `10` and I have seen `8` maybe once or twice.

Why is the UI thread ID usually one of these numbers? (edit) What threads are created before it? Since it varies, I take it the order of creation of the/some threads before it do not matter?

Comment: **The value of the ManagedThreadId property does not vary over time, even if unmanaged code that hosts the common language runtime implements the thread as a fiber.** - Not sure how that helps.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh That's not what he's asking

Comment: Because it's the 9th thread in your managed application since startup, give or take a few threads?

Comment: I suspect .NET itself creates a few threads before the UI starts. The thread used by the garbage collector is probably one of them

Comment: Related [Managed Threads Are Different From Windows Threads](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/managed-threads-are-different-from-windo/228800359)

Comment: Any reasons why do you want to know the answer? I can imagine how many questions "Why" one can ask when allowed, but asking them without reason is pretty pointless.

Comment: The more interesting question is why you care ?!

Comment: @Sinatr Just to learn more, I am interested as to why. Though having the answer would not directly help me in the work I am currently doing.

Comment: If you want to know what threads are created, hook up a debugger (in mixed mode if you want to be complete) and check for yourself. "Thread # created/exited" events will be logged in the output window. By their very nature, thread creation is usually not synchronized, so timing differences mean thread IDs aren't perfectly deterministic over different runs of the application.

Comment: The CLR uses a pretty simple algorithm to generate a new ManagedId for a new thread.  The next one.  Disable the Visual Studio Hosting process option to get a more friendly number, some odds you will now see 1, the first one.  Review the Debug > Windows > Threads debugger window to see threads that are still running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is just because there were some other threads before yours 8, or 9 to be exact.

I assume those threads are for some .NET framework tasks that run in the background. When starting a Windows Forms application, it has already 16 threads running, some related to Visual Studio debugging, others for '.NET System Events', etc.